# iOS presentRenderBuffer blocking

Tags: ios, opengl-es

**Setup:**

- CADisplayLink on main thread, configured to fire every interval
- iOS 10.2
- OpenGLES 2.0
- iPhone 6

.

```
-(void)callbackFromCADisplayLink:(CADisplayLink *)dl
{
   u64 tStart = high_res_clock_now();

   <Process input, advance game world, prepare graphics commands>

   // Frame processed
   u64 prePresentElapsed = high_res_clock_now() - tStart;

   [myEAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];

   // Graphics commands submitted
   u64 postPresentElapsed = high_res_clock_now() - tStart;
}
```

**What I'm finding is:**

- `prePresentElapsed` is consistently in the *0.5-2.5ms* range.
- There are essentially 2 graphics modes:
- "Fast mode": where `postPresentElapsed` is consistently in *1.5-4ms* range
- "Slow mode": where `postPresentElapsed` is consistently hovering at *16ms*
- The system starts in "Fast mode", but degenerates to "Slow mode" seemingly randomly (doesn't appear to be associated with a large frame spike), and then stays in "Slow mode" until the app is put into inactive/background state, then back into active state.

Clearly, it appears `presentRenderbuffer` is blocking due to downstream effects of vsync.

**Questions:**

1. What causes the switch between modes?
2. How can I reliably stay in "Fast mode"

Answer (score 0):

iOS is very active in modifying the clock speed of the CPU and GPU. As far as the OS is concerned, the ideal state is for your app to run consistently at 60fps with the lowest possible clock speed (which sounds like what is happening in your slow mode)

When your app launches, the clock speed starts out high, once things have had a little while to settle down, the OS gets the measure of your app and slows the clock speed down as much as it possibly can without affecting the user experience. It does this to save the users battery and keep the device cool.

It's quite frustrating, because there's no way to disable, control or even monitor this behaviour as far as I'm aware, so it makes performance measurement a lot harder. It also means that you're bound to miss the odd frame when the app has a busy frame, because the clock speed management won't be able to raise the clock speed until it's too late.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I highly doubt this is what is happening.